# PCL: The derived class cannot access the protected method in the base class

Tags: clion, pcl

```
// Create an Octree object
pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudpcl::PointXYZ octree (0.01f);
// Set the input point cloud
octree.setInputCloud (cloud);
// Build the octree
octree.addPointsFromInputCloud ();
// Get the root node of the octree
pcl::octree::OctreeNode* root = octree.getRootNode();
```

pcl::octree::OctreePointCloudpcl::PointXYZ is a derived class of pcl::octree::OctreeBasepcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices.

The IDE being used is CLion, and the version of PCL is 1.13.0.

Why does the last line throw an error:

> `getRootNode` is a protected member of `pcl::octree::OctreeBasepcl::octree::OctreeContainerPointIndices`?

And how to fix it?